# Can I select the number of characters in the function format_string

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a StringType column called `ssn` which content is the following:

```
+---------+
|      ssn|
+---------+
|986-69-2371|
|957305210|
|965741549|
|996118261|
|946899347|
|974393395|
|998771903|
|949429820|
|983662042|
|923785843|
|948-84-1328|
|971-48-1142|
|972-79-2371|
|989498321|
|943129824|
|976849729|
|949-79-5213|
|924761199|
|991718011|
|988-25-4619|
+---------+
```

As you can see the content is not homogeneous. My intention is to format the content so that all rows have the same format (the format I want is `xxx-xx-xxxx`). All the rows have the 9 numbers.
I have done it with the following function:

```
df.withColumn("ssnFormat", when(col("ssn").contains("-"), col("ssn")).otherwise(format_string("%s-%s-%s", col("ssn").substr(1, 3), col("ssn").substr(4, 2), col("ssn").substr(6, 4))))
```

I was wondering, could I do it in a way that in the format expression I specified the characters that I want to take from the string?

This is what I mean:

```
format_string("%3c-%2c-%4c", col("ssn"))
```

In the previous instruction my intention was to select the first characters of the string, then write the hyphen, the 2 following characters, the hyphen and then the remaining characters.

I want to find if this is a possible way because I don't like much the fact that I have to do substring of the parts I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `regexp_replace` function instead by capturing the groups `xxx-xx-xxxx` and replacing by `$1-$2-$3`:

```scala
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "ssn",
  regexp_replace(col("ssn"), "^(\\d{3})-?(\\d{2})-?(\\d{4})$", "$1-$2-$3")
)

df1.show
//+-----------+
//|        ssn|
//+-----------+
//|986-69-2371|
//|957-30-5210|
//|965-74-1549|
//|996-11-8261|
//|946-89-9347|
//|974-39-3395|
//|998-77-1903|
//|949-42-9820|
//|983-66-2042|
//|923-78-5843|
//|948-84-1328|
//|971-48-1142|
//|972-79-2371|
//|989-49-8321|
//|943-12-9824|
//|976-84-9729|
//|949-79-5213|
//|924-76-1199|
//|991-71-8011|
//|988-25-4619|
//+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you mean, similar to the Excel custom formats.  One method is to use `overlay` to insert the dashes at the right point.  This seems similar to the SQL `STUFF` function.  I am still having to use `regexp_replace` to make sure the strings are in a consistent format prior to the change so it's not that elegant:

```
df.select($"ssn", 
    overlay(
        overlay(
            regexp_replace($"ssn", "-", ""), lit("-"), lit(4), lit(0)), lit("-"), lit(7), lit(0)).
    alias("formatted_ssn")).show
```

My results (from Synapse Notebook, Scala language):

[image: Synapse notebook results]

I think @blackbishop's example is more elegant and has an upvote from me.  I just wanted to record a working example of `overlay` and say "I know what you mean and here's how it might look in Scala and there's easier ways to do it.".  I was also looking at `patch` but couldn't get it to work with a dataframe.